# Disconnecting from VSCode tunnel frequently

Tags: jupyter-notebook, vscode-remote

I'm trying to use VSCode remote tunnel to work on my code remotely. I'm quite new to this I couldn't find many configurations on this.

1. What are some ways I can establish a more stable connection or is there any way I can reconnect to the same instance without having to reload?
2. Is there a difference between remote and VSCode SSH in terms of stability and the way of connection? Asking because I need to connect to a VPN on my remote server. The VPN breaks the SSH connection but not the remote.

Things I've tried:

1. I tried to search for the options in VSCode but there was only the SSH settings. I changed it but it didn't improve anything.
2. Probably a very bad comparison, but using teamviewer was more stable in terms of stability.

Additional details: I'm connecting to a windows computer from a mac M1. The VPN is Pulse Secure so if there's any configuration I doubt I have access. I have checked that my versions on both vscodes are updated.